# Break out of Bootstrap modal dialog if unauthenticated

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a site which requires inactive user sessions to expire after 20 minutes for security reasons, this works fine.

There have been a few instances where users have loaded a page which contains links to spawn a modal dialog which loads content from another url on the site, however this url requires the user to be authenticated also. What happens is that a user can still click on a link after their session has expired and instead of getting the expected content they are redirected to the login page but within the modal. The design of the page is not suited for display inside of a modal and I therefore need to break the user out of the modal window.

On standard pages I use the following script to make sure that users are not trapped inside of another sites frames:

```
if (top.location != location) {
    top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
```

This works fine but seems to have no effect within a modal dialog?

The link which spawns the modal is as follows and pretty standard as per the documentation:

```
<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="./JoinWaitingList">Join Waiting List</a>
```

I'm looking for a solution or alternative approaches to the problems if anyone has any ideas please?

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` to hide the modal from your original page (that opened it). [See documentation.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

You cannot close the modal from inside the page loaded into it as content. You could look at the loaded page from outside to check whether the login content was loaded instead, but only if the page is on the same domain as your outer page. (Otherwise you're gonna run in to [cross-domain restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to just close the modal I need the outer page to do a full redirect to the login page hence my check as to whether the top.location was in fact the current page.

Comment: Please try explaining more concisely what you're trying to do. Say you have a page `A` containing a link that opens a modal. Clicking on the link is supposed to load page `B` into the modal. Are you saying that when login page `L` is loaded into the modal instead of `B`, you want `A` to close the modal and perform a hard redirect to `L` instead?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to manually examine the DOM of the loaded page try to find some elements unique to page `L` (see the second paragraph of my answer).